# Macro for saving each sheet in a workbook to CSV file

Tags: macos, vba, excel

First off let me just say that I have been googling this for hours and trying every single code online that I can find, so don't think I haven't tried before asking...

For some reason I get errors with every single one I found. I just want a macro that will save each sheet of a .xlsm workbook to a .csv file. Preferably I would be able to have the macro create a pop up window where I can select the destination path for the CSV files.

This would be using office 2016 for Mac.

Specifically here's one that I just tried:

```
    Sub SaveAllSheetsAsCSV2()
On Error GoTo Heaven

' each sheet reference
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
' path to output to
Dim OutputPath As String
' name of each csv
Dim OutputFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

' ask the user where to save
OutputPath = InputBox("Enter a directory to save to", "Save to directory", Path)

If OutputPath <> "" Then

' save for each sheet
For Each Sheet In Sheets

    OutputFile = OutputPath & "/" & Sheet.Name & ".csv"

    ' make a copy to create a new book with this sheet
    ' otherwise you will always only get the first sheet
    Sheet.Copy
    ' this copy will now become active
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=OutputFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next

End If

Finally:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub

Heaven:
MsgBox "Couldn't save all sheets to CSV." & vbCrLf & _
    "Source: " & Err.Source & " " & vbCrLf & _
    "Number: " & Err.Number & " " & vbCrLf & _
    "Description: " & Err.Description & " " & vbCrLf

GoTo Finally
End Sub
```

The one thing I tried changing was this line:

```
OutputFile = OutputPath & "/" & Sheet.Name & ".csv"
```

Because the "/" was originally a "\" and I'm using mac so I figured that was worth a shot. Neither worked.

Comment: "In Windows Excel 97-2016 and in Mac Excel 2011 you can open files or save files where you want in almost every folder on your system without warnings or requests for permission. But in Mac Office 2016 Microsoft have to deal with Apple’s sandbox requirements. This means that when you want to save or open files the first time you will be prompted to allow access on the first attempt to access such a folder or file. "  http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac020.htm

Comment: Thanks, I tried following the instructions on there but the same thing is happening. I run the macro, it prompts me for permission to access the folder, it copies the content of sheet1 to a file and tries to save it but it says "cannot access sheet1.csv" ... sheet1.csv that it just created never actually saves and just stays open on the desktop. None of the remaining sheets in the .xlsm workbook get processed

Comment: I tried doing this, using the macro recorder. I noted that when you try to Export as CVS, it prompts the user that you can only save a single sheet, and to click "OK".  I see you have turned off `Alerts`, so I'm not sure why it's not saving for you. I'm betting it's the way it expects your Mac file path name to be given.  I think the format should be like this: [ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "Macintosh HD:Users:YourUserName:Desktop:ron.xlsm"](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac020.htm)